# Runtime error when trying to run query on Data.StackExchange

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I am trying to run a query on [Data.StackExchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and I am getting an error accessing any query.

[image]

This error is appearing on any query, [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/74055/questions-per-month-9-functional-languages-compared) or [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73753/posts-tagged-with-viewpager-but-not-android), [any of them](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).

Comment: Well at least you know you're not the only one

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter someone definitely broke it.

Comment: It is working for me now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Data.se was down for a bit while we ran the massive imports to get it up to date.  Enjoy your fresh data.